# Request to follow

Tags: discussion, arabic

I have created a proposal for arabic language learning on area 51, i request all of you to please follow it

https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123316/arabic-language-learning?referrer=N2IyODAwODAyNmQxMzE1NjA0YzA3YzBhOTdkMWNkMWUzOTMwMzQ5YjFiZWIyYjRmZDMxNzYxM2JiOTAwNzA0MxSsm5GXPv-WH8LV-8NJCZRcwVPjS0DmavjA_Vuy2CwT0

as you all know learning arabic language stack exchange is desperately needed as it is realted to understanding of  many islamic texts

Answer (score 1):

[Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123316/arabic-language-learning?referrer=N2IyODAwODAyNmQxMzE1NjA0YzA3YzBhOTdkMWNkMWUzOTMwMzQ5YjFiZWIyYjRmZDMxNzYxM2JiOTAwNzA0MxSsm5GXPv-WH8LV-8NJCZRcwVPjS0DmavjA_Vuy2CwT0) now states:

> This proposal has been deleted.
>
> Proposals with insufficient activity are subject to removal. Occasionally, proposals may also be removed for reasons of moderation: spam, off topic, abuse, etc. For more information, see the FAQ.

---

I get the feeling it's getting increasingly difficult to propose new sites.  Nowadays, you need a pre-existing community in proposals:

> **3. Please link to the organization or website organizing this effort**:
> If you do not yet have a community organized, ready and eager to build your site, please do not submit this proposal.